# Smallest subset of array whose sum is no less than key

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array (lets assume of non negative integers) we are required to find the smallest length subset such that sum of elements is no less than K. K is another integer provided as input.

Is it possible to have a solution with time complexity O(n) [big oh of n]?

my current thinking is along the following lines:
we could sort the array in O(n * log n) and then iterate over the sorted array starting from the largest number and maintaining the running sum until the running sum becomes >= K.

However, this would have worst case running time of O(n * (log n + 1)).

So if anyone could share ideas of doing this in O(n) time, I would really appreciate..

Note: The elements of subarray dont have to be a contiguous sequence of the original array in this context

Comment: Won't sorting mess up the order of the elements? What do you mean by subarray? A contiguous sequence of elements in the array, or a subset of the elements in the array?

Comment: Sorting can't be applied in this case as it will change the order of item.

Comment: I am assuming order is not important. i.e. {1,2,3} and {2,1,3} are treated as same sub arrays. Subrarray referes to a subset of elements and NOT necessarily a contiguous sequence in this context.

Comment: Also, if you think sorting isn't the way to go, what algorithm would you suggest to tackle this?

Comment: There's another way to do this, I'm checking the complexity.

Comment: As I've said in a comment on an answer below, this is a very misleading question. Please change the title to "Smallest subset whose sum is no less than key" or similar, and all references in the body from "subarray" to "subset", and from "length" to "size", to make it clear that element order and contiguity aren't important. I'll then remove the -1.

Comment: Amended the problem title and problem body. Clearer now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a linear time algorithm for finding the K largest numbers - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm. Of course what you want is just enough largest numbers to sum up to at least K.

In the standard selection algorithm, you take a random pivot and then look to see how many numbers fall on each side of it. You then either accept or reject one half, and keep working on the other half. You have just looked at each number in each half, in turn - the cost of each pivot stage is linear, but the amount of data considered at each stage reduces fast enough that the total cost is still only linear.

The cost of a pivot stage will still be only linear if you take the sum of all the numbers above the pivot. Using this, you can work out if accepting all these numbers, together with any numbers previously selected, would give you a collection of numbers that add up to at least K. If it does, you can ditch the other numbers and use the numbers above the pivot for the next pass. If it does not, you can accept all the numbers above the pivot, and use the numbers below the pivot for the next pass. As with the selection algorithm, the pivot itself and any ties give you a few special cases and the possibility of finding an exact answer early.

(So I think you can do this in (randomized) linear time using a modified version of the selection algorithm in which you look at the sum of the numbers above the pivot, instead of how many numbers are above the pivot.

Comment: Surely this is correct (I'll upvote as you beat me in time -;) ). Processing a pivot (counting terms, determining sums, storing indices and whatever else you'll need to know at the end) is an effort linear in the size of the set. In the next stride you process either half of the original set, i.e. an effort linear in N/2. Worst case - not hitting a solution early - is then an overall effort linear in N + N/2 + N/4 + ... = 2N, so O(N) precisely.

Comment: The algorithm for finding the k largest numbers in linear time requires the array to be reordered, so I don't understand how it would apply here. And your recursion doesn't seem to account for the widths of the subarrays either -- even if the sum of all numbers above the pivot is >= k, it might well be that the solution lies in the below-pivot half because these numbers are positioned closer together. -1.

Comment: pls try to give examples..  about boundary cases

Comment: My apologies -- it has become evident that when the OP said "minimum length subarray", he actually meant "smallest subset", and not (for example) "minimum length subarray". +2 (this required a dummy edit).

Comment: Thanks for this. I have marked this as accepted but worth mentioning, that @Bert te Velde 's explanation as an addendum to this explanation, helped!

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a problem for dynamic programming.  When you build your array, you build another array containing the cumulative sum up to each particular index.  So each `i` in that array has the sums from `1..i`.

Now it's easy to see that the sum of values for indices `p..q` is `SUM(q) - SUM(p-1)` (with the special case that `SUM(0)` is `0`).  Obviously I'm using 1-based indices here...  This operation is O(1), so now you just need an O(n) algorithm to find the best one.

A simple solution is to keep track of a `p` and `q` and walk these through the array.  You expand with `q` to begin.  Then you contract `p` and expand `q` repeatedly, like a caterpillar crawling through your array.

To expand `q`:

```
p <- 1
q <- 1

while SUM(q) - SUM(p-1) < K
    q <- q + 1
end while
```

Now `q` is at the position where the subarray sum has just exceeded (or is equal to) `K`.  The length of the subarray is `q - p + 1`.

After the `q` loop you test whether the subarray length is less than your current best.  Then you advance `p` by one step (so that you don't accidentally skip over the optimal solution) and go again.

You don't really need to create the `SUM` array...  You can just build the subarray sum as you go...  You would need to go back to using the 'real' `p` instead of the one just before.

```
subsum <- VAL(1)
p <- 1
q <- 1

while q <= N
    -- Expand
    while q < N and subsum < K
        q <- q + 1
        subsum <- subsum + VAL(q)
    end while

    -- Check the length against our current best
    len <- q - p + 1
    if len < bestlen
        ...
    end if

    -- Contract
    subsum <- subsum - VAL(p)
    p <- p + 1
end while
```

Notes:

> **j_random_hacker said:** it would help to explain exactly why it is acceptable to examine just the O(n) distinct subarrays that this
>   algorithm examines, instead of all O(n^2) possible distinct subarrays

The dynamic programming philosophy is:

1. do not follow solution paths that will lead to a non-optimal result; and
2. use the knowledge of previous solutions to compute a new solution.

In this case a single solution candidate (some `(p,q)` such that `p <= q`) is computed by summing of the elements.  Because those elements are positive integers, we know that for any solution candidate `(p,q)`, the solution candidate `(p,q+1)` will be larger.

And so we know that if `(p,q)` is a minimal solution then `(p,q+1)` is not.  We end our search as soon as we have a candidate, and test whether that candidate is better than any we have seen so far.  That means for each `p`, we only need to test one candidate.  This leads to both `p` and `q` only ever increasing, and thus the search is linear.

The other part of this (using previous solutions) comes from recognising that `sum(p,q+1) = sum(p,q) + X(q+1)` and similarly `sum(p+1,q) = sum(p,q) - X(p)`.  Therefore, we do not have to sum all elements between `p` and `q` at every step.  We only have to add or subtract one value whenever we advance one of the search pointers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1, but it would help to explain exactly why it is acceptable to examine just the O(n) distinct subarrays that this algorithm examines, instead of all O(n^2) possible distinct subarrays.

Comment: Thanks, that covers part of it, but the particular thing I was looking for was why it is safe to start looking from (p, q+1) (instead of way back at (1, q+1)) if we discover that (p, q) is too small.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesnt your answer look for the minimum length "contiguous" sub array? I am looking for a solution where the sub array does not have to be contiguous as capture in my comments in the original questions. Sorry if this wasn't clear. I'll add this detail to the original problem statement as well.

Comment: @AnuragKapur: You *really* should have made that clearer in your question.  If "subarray" doesn't imply "contiguous", then it doesn't mean anything beyond "subset" -- so why not just call your question "Smallest subset of elements whose sum is no less than key"?  "Minimum length subarray" is about as misleading as possible!

Comment: Did make it clear in the comments and then later added it in the OP statement. Anyway, I get your point and will keep this in mind for next time!

Comment: @AnuragKapur Yes, at the time I wrote this answer, everything in the question and comments implied that you were looking for a subarray which in my mind means contiguous.  I have since taken suggestions to improve my answer even though it is not the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The OP made it clear in his answers to comments, that the problem is to find a subset, NOT necessarily a contiguous sequence (the term 'subarray' was admittedly poor). Then, I believe the method indicated by mcdowella is correct, comprising the following steps:

Starting out with N elements, find the MEDIAN element (i.e. the (N/2)-th element imagining a sorted array, which you don't have and don't construct). This is achieved with the "Median of Medians" algorithm, proven to be O(n), see the wiki ref already given and repeated here: [Selection algorithm, see section on the Median of Median algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Having the median element: scan linearly the complete set, and partition in "below" and "above", meanwhile summing, counting and doing whatever you want to keep track of, for each of the "halves". This step is (also) O(N).

Having completed the scan, if the "upper half"-sum is above the target (K), you forget all about the lower half and repeat the procedure for the upper half, whose size is (roughly) N/2. 
If, on the other hand, the "upper half'-sum is less than K, then you add that upper half to the final result, subtract its sum from K and repeat the procedure with the lower half.

Altogether, you process sets of size N, N/2, N/4, N/8 etcetera, each in O(M) with respect to their respective sizes M, and hence the overall stuff is also linear in N, because N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 ... stays below 2N.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the median of medians algorithm and a more detailed explanation. I'll however have mark @mcdowella 's answer as accepted just based on the fact he answered earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, mcDowella deserves the credit, as I in fact already suggested in my earlier comment on his post. I put up "my" answer only because it appeared that mcdowella's was not understood well enough by some others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should be fast enough.
I'm guessing it's almost linear.

```
def solve(A, k):
    assert sum(A) >= k
    max_ = max(A)
    min_ = min(A)
    n = len(A)
    if sum(A) - min_ < k:
        return A
    bucket_size = (max_ - min_)/n + 1
    buckets = []
    for i in range(n):
        buckets.append([])
    for item in A:
        bucket = (item - min_)/bucket_size
        buckets[bucket].append(item)

    solution = []

    while True:
        bucket = buckets.pop() #the last bucket
        sum_ = sum(bucket)
        if sum_ >= k:
            #don't need everything from this bucket
            return solution + solve(bucket, k)
        else:
            k -= sum_
            solution += bucket

print solve([5,2,7,52,30,12,18], 100)
"[52, 30, 18]"
```

Comment: This is essentially a bucket/bin sort, but only recursively sorting the top buckets. I think with the added space complexity, this method will be slower on average than a quickselect based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "sub array" term implies contiguous part of array ([like here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), another problem as example).

So there is simple O(n) algorithm to find minimum length subarray:

Set two indexes (left, right) to the first element and move them till the end of array. Check the sum between these indexes, advance right pointer, if sum is too small (or pointers are equal), advance left if sum is big

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the sub array does not have to be contiguous as made clear in the comments of the OP and I have added this note to the OP statement as well now.

Answer (score 0):

The subarray has to be contiguous by the definition of array.

Use 2 pointers (start, end). Initialize them to the beginning of array.
Track the current sum between (start, end), and move end to right one by one. Every time you move end pointer, sum = sum + array[end].

And when sum >= target, start moving start to the right and keep tracking sum as sum = sum - array[start].

While moving start to the right, keep checking the sum still is no less than target. And we also need to track the length by doing length = end - start + 1, as well as minLength = min(minLength, length).

Now when we have moved both pointers to as right as possible, we just need to return minLength.

The general idea is to first find an "window" that satisfies the condition (sum >= target), then slide the window to right one element at a time and keep the window size minimum every time we move the window.